# Frida - Error: access violation accessing 0x0

Tags: android, frida

I'm running Frida on Android application, After period time I got the following exception:

```
Error: access violation accessing 0x0
     at NativePointer.readU8 (frida/runtime/core.js:144:17)
     at parseLibffiClosureEntrypointForIA32 (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:1165:1)
     at InvocationContext.<anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:1140:1)
Error: access violation accessing 0x0
    at NativePointer.readU8 (frida/runtime/core.js:144:17)
    at parseLibffiClosureEntrypointForIA32 (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:1165:1)
    at InvocationContext.<anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:1140:1)
Error: access violation accessing 0x0
    at NativePointer.readU8 (frida/runtime/core.js:144:17)
    at parseLibffiClosureEntrypointForIA32 (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:1165:1)
    at InvocationContext.<anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:1140:1)
Error: access violation accessing 0x0
    at NativePointer.readU8 (frida/runtime/core.js:144:17)
    at parseLibffiClosureEntrypointForIA32 (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:1165:1)
    at InvocationContext.<anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:1140:1)
```

Frida-server version: frida-server-12.8.10-android-x86.xz

Frida-Node version: 12.8.10

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should edit your post and include the Frida script code you actually execute.

Comment: It's occurred for each frida script code i'm actuaclly running, even just loop with console.log command